# Papaerclip not working with update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, paperclip

I have **Person** model:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  attr_accessible :photo,:name
  has_mongoid_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"

  field :photo
  field :name  
end
```

And in my **update action** of **ManagedbController** I do:

```
def edit
    @person=Person.find_by(name: params[:name])
end

def update
    @person=Person.find_by(name: params[:name])
    @person.update_attributes(photo: params[:photo])
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h2> Add photo here!</h2>
<%= @person.name %>

<%= form_for @person, url: {controller: :managedb,action: :update}, html: {mulitpart: true}  do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.hidden_field :name %></p>
  <p><%= f.file_field :photo %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit :submit , class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %></p>
<% end %>
```

when I visit the edit page I'm getting the name of the person from **@person.name** which means that the @person variable is **NOT NIL**

But when I select a image and **click on submit** I get this error on the **update method**:

> Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
>
> Document not found for class Person with attributes {:name=>nil}.

**At**

```
 @person=Person.find_by(name: params[:name])
```

Request parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"jpm+Ljk6rvZP9bIUw2gA9BvfZXsnATzsIpEEJMTbuzY=", "person"=>{"name"=>"child", "photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ffa20a05330 @original_filename="deepika-padukone-61a.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"person[photo]\"; filename=\"deepika-padukone-61a.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/b2/v1ytdy497fj9md28f7pr9wgm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130911-3884-daf5yu>>}, "commit"=>"submit", "controller"=>"managedb", "action"=>"update"}

Rack session
```

What is wrong here? Help! I'm using Mongoid and Rails 3.2.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give the name of the person in the form, so `params[:name]` is `nil`.
You can add a hidden field to keep the *name* (*id* is better) an get it in your controller with params.

Try this :

```
<h2> Add photo here!</h2>
<%= @person.name %>

<%= form_for @person, url: {controller: :managedb,action: :update}, html: {mulitpart: true}  do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.hidden_field :name %></p>
  <p><%= f.file_field :photo %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit :submit , class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %></p>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

I suggest you to separate your action in `ManageDbController` : 1 to display the form (should be `edit`) and another 1 to update your model (`update` action don't change).

You can also install this 2 gems `better_errors` and `binding_of_caller`, they can help you to debug your issue.

Comment: now it's giving **uninitialized constant PersonsController**. Check my question I have updated it. The update action is in another controller and there's no controller as **PersonsController**

Comment: look at the *action* attribute in the generated html and check the url. It seems `from_for` doesn't care *url* param.

Comment: I'm not understanding what's happening. Now I'm again getting the **Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound**!! The multipart is working though. Updated the question.

Comment: did the `@person` is updated anyway ? the image is uploaded in your file system ??

Comment: i've updated my answer ;). If it doesn't resolve your problem, show your routes please.

Comment: I'm already using the those two gem's. Will try those things now.

Comment: updated the question with what u had suggested. added the edit method and the form fields to `edit.html.erb`. Still getting the **DocumentNotFound error.**

Comment: The error is different. In Mongoid the id is alphanumeric. And rails, in the update method, works only with integer id's. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18822028/2675010)