# Strange AbstractController::ActionNotFound Error with update method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action

I have **FamiliesController** with these actions:

```
def edit
 @family=Family.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @family=Family.find(params[:id])
    @family.update_attributes(params[:family])
end
```

**Family model**: (Using Mongoid)

```
attr_accessible :location
field :location
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
<%= form_for @family do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :location %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </p>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</div>
```

**rotues.rb**

```
resources :families
```

But when I submit the form I get:

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /families/5235513e1dba7f8605000004
>
> The action '5235513e1dba7f8605000004' could not be found for FamiliesController
>
> (5235513e1dba7f8605000004) is id of the person

What is wrong here?

**EDIT**

So I found out on SO and it looks like **Rails does not support alphanumeric IDs** Also the gem mentioned in the answers don't work in mongoid (they are only for ActiveRecord models). So how to sort out this issue for Mongoid?

**Does that mean I cannot use the Rails update method to update my database records in Mongoid?**

Comment: I'm having the same problem.Hope someone helps!

Comment: What is `5235513e1dba7f8605000004`? Is that the `id`? How come it is alphanumeric?

Comment: @RajeshKolappakam Yeah it is the id of the person I'm passing. Using mondoid. It's the id which Mongoid automatically creates on making a new object (in this case a Family).

Comment: if you are not trying something special with your model, it should work fine. alphanumeric id should not make any difference here. Could you please put your family.rb code here and also routes if possible. I just tried a demo app with mongoid, it works as expected

Comment: using alphanumeric ids shouldn't cause any problems. it seems something is wrong with your routes.

Comment: try 1. to put your resources :families to the top of routes.rb 2. check if your form is really sending a PUT request, not POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the

> resources :families

to top of the **routes.rb**. And now it works fine.

Don't no why it is so.

Comment: Well I tried the same thing and it's working now. Don't know what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not support alphanumeric IDs by default, it expects an integer.

If you need to make the IDs alphanumeric, you need to make some changes. Please look at the following resources:

- [Altering the primary key in Rails to be a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750413/altering-the-primary-key-in-rails-to-be-a-string)
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Comment: But that is mongoid defaults. Isn't there a way to make mongoid make non-alphanumeric IDs?

Comment: So will this happen everytime with mongoid?